# SimpleDateFormat is returning date with leading zeros like 0022 Feb 2018

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat, date-formatting

This is my `SimpleDateFormat` instance:

```
public static final SimpleDateFormat DD_MMM_YYYY =
                new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
```

I'm converting timestamps in milliseconds to this date format.

Sometimes it returns the correct date like:

> 22 Feb 2018

But sometimes (in rare cases) it returns an incorrect date like:

> 0022 Feb 2018

Why is it adding two leading zeros?

My method is below-

```
public static String convertLongToDate(long timestamp) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
        long todaysTimestamp = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
        long yesterdayTimestamp = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
        String timeString;

        String todaysDateStr = DD_MMM_YYYY.format(todaysTimestamp);
        String givenDateStr = DD_MMM_YYYY.format(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

        Log.d("Check", "date-> todaysDateStr=" + todaysDateStr + ", givenDateStr=" + givenDateStr+", todayLength="+todaysDateStr.length()+", givenLength="+givenDateStr.length());
        if (todaysDateStr.equalsIgnoreCase(givenDateStr)) {
            timeString = AppConstants.TODAY;
        } else if (DD_MMM_YYYY.format(yesterdayTimestamp).equalsIgnoreCase(givenDateStr)) {
            timeString = AppConstants.YESTERDAY;
        } else {
            timeString = givenDateStr;
        }
        timeString = timeString.trim();
        return timeString;
    }
```

Comment: never gonna happen so i think its ur mistake

Comment: What do you mean by sometimes? You run the same code 1000 times and a few times it's just with leading zeroes? Anything modifying the value in between?

Comment: Nothing is modifying value, there is a function which takes timestamp in milliseconds and convert it in given format.

Comment: Can you show some code that produces this?

Comment: Michael - Edit my question with method

Comment: The `SimpleDateFormat` class is long outdated and notoriously troublesome. Consider adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project so you can use [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) instead. It is so much nicer to work with. And its classes are thread-safe; my guess is that this fact will solve your problem.

Comment: **This Question is now moot**, as the terrible `Calendar` and `SimpleDateformat` classes are supplanted by the *java.time* classes. Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without more info about how you're using the formatter, it's hard to tell what the problem is.

But my guess is that it happens because `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread-safe.

When running it in a multi-thread environment, strange things start to happen. Just check at google and you'll find lots of articles about that: https://www.google.com/search?q=simpledateformat+not+thread+safe

#### Update:

Using your code, I can't reproduce the problem, but I still think it's related to using a non-threadsafe class in a multithread environment - it's the only situation I know that problems like this can happen, specially the "sometimes" factor.

**Silly question:** does any of the `AppConstants` values have leading zeroes? Just asking, who knows...

#### Alternatives

You can use a better API for that, such as ThreeTen Backport: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48911470

With that, your code becomes much more clear and easy to understand/maintain:

```
public static String convertLongToDate(long timestamp) {
    DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy");
    ZonedDateTime today = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    ZonedDateTime yesterday = today.minusDays(1);

    ZonedDateTime givenDate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());

    String timeString;
    // compare just the date (day, month, year)
    // no need to convert to string to compare if dates are the same
    if (today.toLocalDate().equals(givenDate.toLocalDate())) {
        timeString = AppConstants.TODAY;
    } else if (yesterday.toLocalDate().equals(givenDate.toLocalDate())) {
        timeString = AppConstants.YESTERDAY;
    } else {
        timeString = givenDate.format(f);
    }
    timeString = timeString.trim();
    return timeString;
}
```

This API is threadsafe and those strange things that happen sometimes with `SimpleDateFormat` don't happen here.

Or, if you don't want to use another API, you can use the solutions of this post: http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com.br/2010/08/dateformat-with-multiple-threads.html

Comment: AppConstants doesn't have any zeros. The problem can be thread-safety. Will implement your code and let you know.

Comment: +1. The code using ThreeTen Backport (and on Android, [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP)) is not only clearer to read, quite importantly it’s thread-safe because the modern classes are. You can make it still a bit simpler by using `LocalDate` everywhere, the only place you need one `ZonedDateTime` is in the conversion of the `long` timestamp, so just convert on to `LocalDate` immediately.

Comment: @MohitRajput You can also use the solutions with ThreadLocal, as explained here: http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com.br/2010/08/dateformat-with-multiple-threads.html

Comment: `DateTimeFormatter` being thread-safe you can safely let it be `public static final` as the formatter in the question.

Answer (score 0):

if you show current date and specific format then used below code.

```
Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime(); // get current date and time.
    System.out.println("Current time => " + c);

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy"); // define your format.
    String formattedDate = df.format(c);
    System.out.println("New Date To Show::"+formattedDate);
```

Comment: I'm doing the same thing. Please check my code, I have updated my question.